# Is this an appropriate place for me to ask how to download all files from a category or article on a Wikimedia project?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'd like to ask how to download all the files from a single category or article on a Wikimedia project, more specifically Wikimedia Commons in an automated manner (i.e., I just want to run a single script to get this result and not have to download them all manually myself from my browser), but I'm wondering if this would be better asked at SuperUser SE as I'm on 64 bit Windows 7 or here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a member of both communities, I think that kind of question would be better suited for Super User. Wikimedia Commons isn't a webapp *per se*, and you're asking about how to download files to the computer, which places your question more in SU's domain.

Please note that your question is more likely to be answered if you describe some of the research you have done about this problem; "gimme teh codez" posts are generally frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

The [Wikimedia Commons Help Desk](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Help_desk) is probably a better place to ask. You're guaranteed to be able to interact with experts on the software there.

If you're bound and determined to ask on a Stack Exchange site, then I think this one or [Super User](http://superuser.com) are appropriate; I just don't know that you'll get the answer you need.

Stack Exchange sites are great, but sometimes you really need to go to the source.